# linq query repeated columns in a list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, generic-collections

I have a table similar to the one below.

```
Branch      Dept        Product ID  Product Val Product Date
Branch 1        Dept 1      ID 1        1       5/23/2013
Branch 1        Dept 1      ID 2        1       5/23/2013
Branch 1        Dept 2      ID 3        1       5/23/2013
Branch 2        Dept 11     ID 4        1       5/23/2013
Branch 2        Dept 11     ID 5        1       5/23/2013
Branch 2        Dept 11     ID 6        1       5/23/2013
Branch 3        Dept 21     ID 7        1       5/23/2013
```

I am trying to use LINQ(am a rookie to LINQ) to load this as a collection of objects into an object like:

```
Products = { Branch1 { Dept1 {ID1,ID2}, 
                       Dept2 {ID3}}, 
             Branch2 { Dept11 {ID4, ID5, ID6}}, 
             Branch3 { Dept21 {ID7 }
           }
```

And I have trying bit hard working overnight but could not get the right solution. So far I have achieved the following code;

```
var branches = (from p in ProductsList
    select p.Branch).Distinct();
var products = from s in branches
    select new
    {
        branch = s,
        depts = (from p in ProductsList
            where p.Branch == s
            select new
            {
                dept = p.Dept,
                branch = s,
                prod = (from t in ProductsList
                    where t.Branch = s
                    where t.Dept == p.Dept
                    select t.ProductID)
            })
    };
```

where ProductsList is the list object of the whole table date List

Any help at the earliest is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hierarchically group data using LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230202/how-can-i-hierarchically-group-data-using-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for soemthing like that if you really wanna use linq.

Somethimes, a few foreach are much clearer !

```
var myDic = ProductList
                .GroupBy(m => m.Branch)
                .ToDictionary(
                    m => m.Key,
                    m => m.GroupBy(x => x.Dept)
                          .ToDictionary(
                              x => x.Key,
                              x => x.Select(z => z.ProductId)));
```

result will be  a

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>
```

where first dictionary Key is `Branch`, inner dictionary key is `Dept`, and string list are `ProductId`

which seem to correpond to your wanted result.

Comment: Thank you Raphael and Dave.
Both the solutions worked and Raphael's suited my scenario better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Products.
    .Select(prop => prop.Branch)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(b => new 
    {
        Branch = b,
        Departments = Products
            .Where(p => p.Branch == b)
            .Select(p => p.Dept)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(d => new 
            {
                Products = Products
                    .Where(p => p.Department == d)
                    .Select(p => p.ProductID)
                    .Distinct()
            })
    })
```